# Change Font, Style, etc. Of Objects Based On Orientation Of Device Swift

Tags: ios, swift, orientation

I'm creating a calculator app for iPhone with Xcode and the latest version of Swift. So, here's my question: how could you change the style, design, font, etc. of objects inside of the user's view if the user rotates his/her phone? This is kind of what I would like it to look like: https://twitter.com/applesupport/status/974004699329376256?lang=en Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is a conditional interface design. The idea when constructing a conditional interface is that you design first for the most general case. When you’ve done that, and when you want to do something different for a particular size class situation, you’ll describe that difference in the `Attributes` or `Size inspector`, or design that difference in the canvas:

*In the Attributes or Size inspector*:

Look for a Plus symbol to the left of a value in the Attributes or Size inspector. This is a value that you can vary conditionally, depending on the environment’s size class at runtime. Click it to see a popover from which you can choose a specialized size class combination. When you do, that value now appears twice: once for the general case, and once for the specialized case which is marked using **wC** **hR** notation. You can now provide different values for those two cases.
The w and h stand for “width” and “height,” corresponding to the trait collection’s `.horizontalSizeClass` and `.verticalSizeClass` respectively; the R and C stand for `.regular` and `.compact`.

*In the canvas*:

Click the Vary for Traits button, to the right of the device types buttons. Two checkboxes appear, allowing you to specify that you want to match the width or height size class (or both) of the current size class. Any designing you now do in the canvas will be applied only to that width or height size class (or both), also modifying the Attributes or Size inspector as needed.

You can design directly into your interface a complex rearrangement of the interface this way when an iPhone app rotates to compensate for a change in device orientation.